# Spring Data Neo4j: ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type byte for value

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-neo4j

I try to store an image as byte array (byte[]) with Spring Data Neo4j and have a following model property:

```
@GraphProperty(propertyType = byte[].class)
private byte[] profileImage;
```

Saving and also reading does not work:

```
modelRepository.save(myObject)
myModel = modelRepository.findByNodeId(nodeId)
```

I receive following Conversion exceptions:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type byte for value ...
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41) ~[spring-core-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174) ~[spring-core-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToArrayConverter.convert(StringToArrayConverter.java:63) ~[spring-core-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:35) ~[spring-core-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174) ~[spring-core-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ...
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Byte.java:148) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.Byte.valueOf(Byte.java:204) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.Byte.valueOf(Byte.java:230) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
```

It seems so that somehow internally the byte[] gets converted first to String then again back to byte[]...

I don't understand exactly what's going on there.

As a connection class I use this one in my Spring app config xml file:

```
org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase
```

Do you have any clue?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

After some investigations I could resolve the issue by providing a custom converter:

```
public class StringBase64ToByteArrayConverter implements Converter<String, byte[]> {

    @Override
    public byte[] convert(String source) {
        return Base64.decodeBase64(source);
    }
}
```

and registering the ConversionService with this converter:

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="my.converter.StringBase64ToByteArrayConverter"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

See also Spring Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#core-convert